# How do I format this date string in R '20150703'?

Tags: r, date, format

This should be simple but I can't figure it out. How should I go about formatting dates that are '20150703' into '07-03-2015'? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may use `format` after converting to 'Date' class

```
 format(as.Date(dates, '%Y%m%d'), '%m-%d-%Y')
 #[1] "07-03-2015"
```

#### data

```
  dates <- '20150703'
```

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look at `lubridate` package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html) which makes it easier to work with dates.

```
ymd("20150703")
```

gives

```
[1] "2015-07-03 UTC"
```

Comment: This is not the output OP wanted.